# GHC profiler output

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I have been going through a [blog](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/05/anatomy-of-a-thunk-leak/) discussing space leaks in Haskell and have been trying to understand the graph output provided by the ghc profiler (after using hp2ps)

Specifically this is the code that I am looking at:

```
main = print (f [1..4000000] (0 :: Int, 1 :: Int))

f [] c = c   
f (x:xs) c = f xs (tick x c) 

tick x (c0,c1) | even x = (c0,c1+1)
               | otherwise = (c0+1,c1)
```

I ran the program with -hb flag for biographical profiling of the heap:

[image: Biographical profile of heap]

I can't understand why so much memory is being considered in the void category as it means that a lot of memory is being allocated to objects that are never used. I restricted a producer profile to just the void components getting output for producer profile restricted to void component:

[image: hc output restricted to void]

Is there some way to find out what exactly what thunks are being formed that lead do the void usage?

Comment: By the way: `f` is essentially a left fold, non strict. This is already "bad", since it will always allocate a huge number of thunks, no matter what `tick` does. I'd make that strict, and would also make `tick` force the components of the output pair. This is not what you are asking, but I can't see if you understand what's going on and you just want a confirmation in the profiling data (so to learn how to deal with more complex cases in the future).

Comment: By the way, I compiled your exact code with -O2, on GHC 8.0.1, and got <100kB memory usage. Without -O2 I get horrible performance.

Comment: On GHC 7.10.3 with -O2 it takes a little over 100MB, its a lot better than the unoptimised version. Seems there have been great improvements in 8.0.1

Comment: The profiler has told you which cost centres result in the allocation - it is the CAFs. Since you don't manually define CAFs, you need to look at the core for your program to see which expressions have become CAFs (unless you have a remarkable level of insight and experience and can predict exactly how the compiler compiles your program).

Answer (score 1):

Use more (local) variables. Replace

```
main = print (f [1..4000000] (0 :: Int, 1 :: Int))
```

with

```
main = print (f list (0 :: Int, 1 :: Int))
   where
   list = [1..4000000]
```

In such way, you will see an entry `main.list/main/Main.CAF` showing exactly how much space the 4M-long list takes. You'll probably find out that it takes a lot of space, since it is being defaulted to `[Integer]`. Define it as `[Int]` to improve space.

Further, `f/main/...` is already shown to take a lot of space in your own post. Indeed, it is similar to a left non-strict fold, which has bad performance.

Making things stricter, we get

```
f [] c = c   
f (x:xs) c = f xs $! tick x c 

tick x (c0,c1) | even x = (,) c0 $! c1+1
               | otherwise = ((,) $! c0+1) c1
```

And now the code runs in constant time, even without using `Int`.

GHC 8.0.1 would also do this optimization automatically if we turn on optimization with `-O2`.

Generally, though, it's a good idea to use explicit type annotations, so that GHC does not introduce unwanted/unneeded polymorphism, and performs better type checks. This could also trigger more optimizations, in general.

Comment: Thanks, I do realize that making the arguments strict by adding bang notation will make the program work with a lot less space. But I am more interested in finding out what thunks are being created.

Comment: I believe the evaluation of f [1,2,3,4] would go through these stages

f [2,3,4] tick 1 (0,1) ->
f [3,4] tick 2 (tick 1 (0,1)) ->
...
tick 4 (tick 3 ( tick 2 (tick 1 (0,1)))) ->

a series of thunks of ticks, which would then evaluate to 

tick 4 (tick 3 ( tick 2 (0+1,1))) ->
tick 4 (tick 3 (0+1, 1+1)) ->
...
(((0+1)+1),((1+1)+1)) 

which is a series of thunks of (+). However I am not able to correlate these stages of the computation with points in the graph, (particularly with the void component which suggests that objects are created but never used)

Comment: @SureshSudhakaran I see. I guess the profiler will not show you all these thunks. However, we can see their total cost attributed to who created the thunks. `f` creates the `tick`-thunks quickly, which are then consumed more slowly by `print`. After `f` finally returns a pair, `print` will force the first component which will start allocating the `+1+1...` thunks (first black spike). Then, `print` does the same for the second component (second black spike).

Comment: Wouldn't the memory allocation for `+1+1` already have happened when the sequence of ticks were evaluated?

Comment: @SureshSudhakaran I'm also unable to correlate the `-hb` plot with the execution. I have no idea about the void part being like that, I find the `-hc` output clearer.

Comment: @SureshSudhakaran No, they weren't evaluated yet. First you build the `tick (tick (tick ...))` large thunk. Then you evaluate that, producing `(x,y)` where both `x,y` are unevaluated thunks `1+1+1+..` (roughly). Last, you perform those `+1`s.

Comment: When we evaluate the `tick (tick (tick ...)))` large thunk, wouldn't have allocated the memory for the  `+1` s?


`tick 3 (tick 2 ( tick 1 (0,1)))`

`tick 3 tick 2 (0+1,1)` (Would new memory for `+1`be allocated at this stage?

Comment: Would evaluating the `+1` s require additional memory?

Comment: The `+1` thunks are allocated when the `tick`s are evaluated, yes. But when `f` builds the `tick` thunk, the `+1` thunks are not yet allocated. When finally evaluating the `+1`s there should be virtually no more memory involved.

Comment: If all the `+1` s are allocated when the `tick` thunk is evaluated, I dont understand how there would be two black spikes. I wonder if it is possible to find 'what thunk' is being created at those points.